# Use a proxy with ASANA API - Python

Tags: python, proxy, asana, asana-api

I'm using the ASANA API to automate some mundane tasks in ASANA using Python. I work for a large government education department which uses a web proxy to which I have no knowledge of the back end or access to configuration. I do know the proxy address and port as well as my credentials to get through it.

Is there a way for me to configure the ASANA API to use this proxy when making requests?

I am connecting to the API using this code:

```
import asana

configuration = asana.Configuration()
configuration.access_token = PAT

api_client = asana.ApiClient(configuration)

sections_api_instance = asana.SectionsApi(api_client)
tasks_api_instance = asana.TasksApi(api_client)
```